# How do I structure a validation loop to ensure that random placed ships fall within bounds?

Tags: ruby

Here is a stripped-down class for Board, and one for Ship.

What I can't get to work is, when I make a new instance of Ship, I want the values to be checked with `Board.new.within_board_bounds(ship)?` before it creates my new object.

If the return value is false, I want the `initialize` method to run again until the test returns true. Only then will the ship object be instantiated.

I tried recursively calling `Ship.new` every time the test value is false, and tried a `while` loop calling `Ship.new`, all with unfortunate results.
What's the right way to do this?

```
class Board

  def initialize
    @grid = {
        1 => {"A"=>".", "B"=>".", "C"=>".", "D"=>".", "E"=>".", "F"=>".", "G"=>".", "H"=>".", "I"=>".", "J"=>"."},
        2 => {"A"=>".", "B"=>".", "C"=>".", "D"=>".", "E"=>".", "F"=>".", "G"=>".", "H"=>".", "I"=>".", "J"=>"."},
        3 => {"A"=>".", "B"=>".", "C"=>".", "D"=>".", "E"=>".", "F"=>".", "G"=>".", "H"=>".", "I"=>".", "J"=>"."},
        4 => {"A"=>".", "B"=>".", "C"=>".", "D"=>".", "E"=>".", "F"=>".", "G"=>".", "H"=>".", "I"=>".", "J"=>"."},
        5 => {"A"=>".", "B"=>".", "C"=>".", "D"=>".", "E"=>".", "F"=>".", "G"=>".", "H"=>".", "I"=>".", "J"=>"."},
        6 => {"A"=>".", "B"=>".", "C"=>".", "D"=>".", "E"=>".", "F"=>".", "G"=>".", "H"=>".", "I"=>".", "J"=>"."},
        7 => {"A"=>".", "B"=>".", "C"=>".", "D"=>".", "E"=>".", "F"=>".", "G"=>".", "H"=>".", "I"=>".", "J"=>"."},
        8 => {"A"=>".", "B"=>".", "C"=>".", "D"=>".", "E"=>".", "F"=>".", "G"=>".", "H"=>".", "I"=>".", "J"=>"."},
        9 => {"A"=>".", "B"=>".", "C"=>".", "D"=>".", "E"=>".", "F"=>".", "G"=>".", "H"=>".", "I"=>".", "J"=>"."},
        10 => {"A"=>".", "B"=>".", "C"=>".", "D"=>".", "E"=>".", "F"=>".", "G"=>".", "H"=>".", "I"=>".", "J"=>"."}
    }
  end

  def within_board_bounds?(ship)
    return false if ship.row + (ship.shipspan) > 10 && ship.direction == "down"
    return false if ship.row - (ship.shipspan) < 0  && ship.direction == "up"
    return false if ship.col + (ship.shipspan) > 10 && ship.direction == "right"
    return false if ship.col - (ship.shipspan) < 0  && ship.direction == "left"
    true
  end
end

class Ship
  attr_reader :shipspan, :size, :row, :col, :ship_type, :direction
  def initialize(ship_type)
      @row = rand(10) + 1                                    # 1-10
      @col = rand(10) + 1                                    # 1-10
      @colAlpha = [0, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
                  'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'][col]              # A-J
      @direction = ['up', 'down', 'right', 'left'].sample    # up, down, right, or left
      case ship_type
        when 'Aircraft Carrier'
          @size = 5
          @shipcode = 'A'
        when 'Battleship'
          @size = 4
          @shipcode = 'B'
        when 'Cruiser'
          @size = 3
          @shipcode = 'C'
        when 'Destroyer'
          @size = 2
          @shipcode = 'D'
        when 'Submarine'
          @size = 1
          @shipcode = 'S'
        else
          @size = 0
          @shipcode = '?'
      end
      @shipspan = size - 1

    puts "success #{@colAlpha} #{@row} #{@direction} #{@size}"
  end
end

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ac = Ship.new("Aircraft Carrier")
p ac

p Board.new.within_board_bounds?(ac)
```

Comment: You always need to check the other axis, even if it's not the way the ship is oriented - ships *do* have a width! As such the function (with `.. && ship.direction == ..`) is trivially wrong. I would make a function that returns the *upper left* and *lower right* bounds of a ship, as a rectangle, then just make sure the square is entirely on board, which is trivial. (These same coordinates could also be used for checking "hit detection".)

Comment: Also, I would use a 2d array/matrix for the grid, such that it can be accessed as `grid[x][y]`, where x and y are numbers in the range `[0,width)`. The letters are the *representation* of the column (e.g. for *output display*), but will otherwise be hard to process!

Comment: Thanks. But if I fix all that I'll still come back to the same point. ... how to reject ships that fail the test and accept only those that return true.

Comment: Independently of the direct answer to your question, I wouldn't have `initialize` be so clever. It means you can never build a Ship with fixed, arbitrary characteristics (which would be necessary if you want a human player to place their ships). First pick random parameters (type, position, orientation), then pass them to a stupid initializes that just returns the ship you asked for, then check for acceptable placement. If it's OK, you have your ship, if it's not, just throw it away and start over.

Comment: so pull the random out of initialize... I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last part of the code would make sense if it were

```
board = Board.new
begin
  ac = Ship.new("Aircraft Carrier")
end until board.within_board_bounds?(ac)
```

Comment: Thanks - I have valid ships!